# Running asp.net code after all web page attributes are loaded

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

This is the html code (part of it):

```
<input type="hidden" name="Recieved" id="Recieved" value="yuval" />
```

(the value is recieved from another page, I wrote this just to explain the problem)
in the cs (asp) page I get a Null Reference Exception here:

```
recieve= Request["Recieved"];
if (!recieve.Equals(""))
```

When I debugged the page and created break point just before the if statement the recieve parameter was null so I think the problem is that the html code is loaded after the asp code and then there is still no Recieved field. 
I found code that didn't work for me:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.LoadComplete += new EventHandler(Page_LoadComplete);
}
```

(after this there is the Page_LoadComplete function code)
How can I load the html attributes and set their values before the asp code runs?

Comment: This has nothing to do with when HTML code is loaded. Your ASP.NET code, running on the server, can't load until the user has clicked a button or taken whatever action will cause a postback. That's long after the page has loaded. See "[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)"

Answer (score 1):

Try this in page load

```
var recieved = Request.Params["Recieved"];
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(recieved))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

This code assumes you are sending a param named Recieved using POST or QueryString